# ¿Qué significa "cdta" en una receta?

Tags: traducción, comida, abreviaturas

En [esta receta](http://www.directoalpaladar.com/postres/la-clasica-torta-marmol), se dice:

> 1 cdta. de polvo de hornear
>   1 cdta. de esencia de vainilla

Google traduce "1 cdta" como "tsp" (teaspoon) y también como "tbsp" (tablespoon). ¿Cuál es la correcta?  ¿Y es una abreviatura de qué?

En este contexto, creo que "teaspon" es correcto, porque "1 tablespoon" (15ml) de esencia de vainilla sería mucho, pero quiero estar seguro.

Comment: +1 just because I know how painful it can be to follow a recipe when you lack dominance of a language. In my case is English and I always need to have a dictionary by my side :)

Comment: Offtopic: CUIDADO, no a nivel idiomático sino a la hora de cocinar, a veces una cucharadita también puede ser de café (que seria como 1/2 tsp) y no de postre (que es algo menos que una tsp). Aunque por los ingredientes mejor una tsp. Por cierto Tbsp suele indicarse con"una cucharada sopera"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

cdta es "cucharadita", esto es, una cucharilla de postre, por lo que sí, teaspoon parece lo más apropiado.

Answer (score 1):

En el proyecto Wikilengua, más precisamente en el capítulo [Ortotipografía en gastronomía](https://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Ortotipograf%C3%ADa_en_gastronom%C3%ADa) se indican algunas abreviaturas relacionadas con las cantidades y proporciones. Entre ellas, se encuentra la que buscas, **cdta.**:

- c/s, c. s.: cuchara sopera
- c/p, c. p.: cuchara de postre
- c/c, c. c.: cuchara de café
- cda.: cucharada
- cdta.: cucharadita

Su equivalencia en inglés es, sin duda, "teaspoon".